# Image rotation reduces resolution in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm building a plane dial simulator using picturebox and I rotate the needle to show the values although every time the image rotates, the image resolution goes down.

```
bmAS = new Bitmap(pictureBoxAirSpeed.Image);
height = bmAS.Height;
width = bmAS.Width;
...
public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap bmp, float angle)
        {
            var rotatedBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            rotatedBitmap.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBitmap))
            {
                g.TranslateTransform(rotatedBitmap.Width / 2, rotatedBitmap.Height / 2);
                g.RotateTransform(angle);
                g.TranslateTransform(-bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2);
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
            }

            bmp.Dispose();

            return rotatedBitmap;
        }
```

I'm not really familiar with C# or image processing, I'm using a code I found in the site. I tried both with and without the SetResolution method.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0. Here's the
[needle right at the start of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOZGm.png) and
[needle after some rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3msIo.png)

Comment: How do you know the image resolution goes down?

Comment: Guessing you mean that rotation produces image artifacts?  Post before and after images and we might be able to tell you what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to upload the images, they're there now

Comment: Are you repeatedly passing the rotated image back into the Rotate function?  If so, instead, you should keep track of the angle (from the origin) and rotate the original bitmap.

Comment: Yes, I'm repeating the process. But if I don't create the bitmap before the function, it doesn't work.

```void update(float angleAS, float angleVS)
        {
            bmVS = new Bitmap(pictureBoxVS.Image);
            bmAS = new Bitmap(pictureBoxAirSpeed.Image);
            pictureBoxAirSpeed.Image = RotateBitmap(bmAS, angleAS);
            pictureBoxVS.Image = RotateBitmap(bmVS, angleVS);
            angle1 = angleAS;
            angle2 = angleVS;
        }```

I tried it right after InitializeComponent, then there's this: System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

Comment: What I am referring to is rotating an already rotated image, where instead you should rotate the original by the amount of the combined rotations.  eg. `var org = BitMap(..); var rot1 = Rotate(org, 20); var rot2 = Rotate(rot1, 30);` would instead be `var rot2 = Rotate(org, 50);`

Comment: I understand that, my problem is to set this original image outside the function and never update it

Comment: Not quite sure.  I was thinking you create a new BitMap of the original each time before rotating, but i am not sure if that is the correct approach (though it should work as expected).

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I may search how to save the Bitmap without using the pictureBox, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the original bitmap when performing the rotation, and keep track of the angle for future rotations.  The issue seems to be that the rotated image is being used for future rotations.  This causes unwanted artifacts and the error grows the more times the image is rotated.

Create a class variable for the original bitmap, this will be used for all rotations, assign it after `InitializeComponent()`.  Create a class variable for the rotated bitmap so we can dispose of bitmaps as we create new ones.  Create a class variable for tracking the angle (not sure if this matters in your use case).

```
private Bitmap orgBitmap;
private Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
private float angle;

public RotateForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    orgBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image);
}
```

We also need to remove the `Dispose` line from `RotateBitmap()`.  This line prevents us from using the same bitmap in the future, so lets get rid of that.

```
bmp.Dispose();  // <- remove
```

Now we can use `orgBitmap` in the rotate function as many times as needed.  We do need to be conscious of the bitmaps we are creating and make sure we are disposing them.  This is where the `rotatedBitmap` variable comes into play.  Before rotating check if a rotated bitmap already exists, and if it does dispose of it.  If your application continues to run after closing this form, make sure to dispose of both the `orgBitmap` and `rotatedBitmap` variables.

I made a simple example on my end using a timer.
Below is the tick callback, which is a good usage example.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    angle += 15;
    angle = angle % 360;

    if (rotatedBitmap != null)
    {
        rotatedBitmap.Dispose();
    }

    rotatedBitmap = RotateBitmap(orgBitmap, angle);
    pictureBox.Image = rotatedBitmap;
}
```